# Как отследить, что карта отрендерилась и на ней отобразились все geoObjects

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создаю карту и на нее добавляю geoObjects из objectManager

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager/ - вообщем по аналогии с этим.

После того, как все элементы отобразятся мне нужно открыть ballon с нужным id
Вопрос как понять что все объекты отрендерилась на карте?

Answer (score 1):

Такого события в JS API Яндекс.Карт нет.

Можно вручную отслеживать добавление оверлеев геообъектов на карту через события [objectManager.objects.overlays](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.OverlayCollection.html)

Получить список видимых объектов (для которых должны появиться оверлеи) во вьюпорте можно через **objectManager.objects.each** и **objectManager.getObjectState**.
Оверлеи создаются только для объектов в видимой области карты.